# ios11 Attach custom view below UISearchController UISearchBar that hides with the Searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I had a `UISearchBar` with which i attached a custom view below which gave some buttons for filtering and sorting... now i want to use the ios11 `UISearchController`that provides a searchbar which smoothly hides into the top NavigationBar. I looked around some and tested a few things but cant figure it out properly. The custom view should hide when scrolling up as well.

Any tips or anything i can read up to get a hold on this? (I'm relatively new to ios development)